# How to test the AZURE ZipDeploy api using postman?

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, kudu

I tried to test the kudu's zipdeploy Api from Azure using Postman by adding the .zip file to the url (https://*******-8257.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy). But it shows 401-invalid credentials. I've given my username and password of my azure account in authorization area. I am not sure whether i need to pass any bearer token. Please help[(Please refer the screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxp5t.jpg)

Comment: Please use deployment credentials(not azure account), detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deployment-credentials)

Comment: Thanks @IvanYang. But now I am getting a 500-internal server error.("Central Directory corrupt Inner Exception:An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file). Any idea?

Comment: I have an similar issue. But in postman -> body, when I change the form-data to binary, it works ok and returns 200. screenshot is [here](https://yytest.blob.core.windows.net/test123/postman-200okk.jpg).

Comment: I changed it to binary and guess what?... It works!!.. Many thanks..@IvanYang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postman -> body -> change the form-data to binary, and then it works at my side.

[image]